# Exclude a list of tests with py.test but on the command line?

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

I would like to exclude a list (about 5 items) of tests with py.test.

I would like to give this list to py.test via the command line.

I would like to avoid to modify the source.

How to do that?

Comment: Have you tried using argparse ?

Comment: @IMCoins in my context py.test is a command line tool. I can't modify python source in this context. Since argparse is a python library I think this does not help here.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You could use [tests selecting expression](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#specifying-tests-selecting-tests), option is `-k`. If you have following tests:

```
def test_spam():
    pass

def test_ham():
    pass

def test_eggs():
    pass
```

invoke pytest with:

```
pytest -v -k 'not spam and not ham' tests.py
```

you will get:

```
collected 3 items

pytest_skip_tests.py::test_eggs PASSED             [100%]

=================== 2 tests deselected ===================
========= 1 passed, 2 deselected in 0.01 seconds =========
```

Answer (score 2):

You could get this to work by creating a `conftest.py` file:

```
# content of conftest.py

import pytest
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--skiplist", action="store_true",
                     default="", help="skip listed tests")

def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config, items):
    tests_to_skip = config.getoption("--skiplist")
    if not tests_to_skip:
        # --skiplist not given in cli, therefore move on
        return
    skip_listed = pytest.mark.skip(reason="included in --skiplist")
    for item in items:
        if item.name in tests_to_skip:
            item.add_marker(skip_listed)
```

You would use it with:

```
$ pytest --skiplist test1 test2
```

Note that if you always skip the same test the list can be defined in `conftest`.

See also [this useful link](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#control-skipping-of-tests-according-to-command-line-option)

Comment: The link helped me.

Answer (score 0):

The rest of the answers are great, but just an additional way would be to use `-k-test_name`

So, e.g:

```
def test_blue():
    pass

def test_black():
    pass
```

You can pass `pytest -k-test_blue` to ignore the test case test_blue.

Something like the following should be observed:

```
===== 1 passed, 1 deselected in 0.31 seconds =====
```

Comment: Does not work for me. Do you mean `pytest --deselect=test_blue tests.py`?